# Regular Backup Script for Apache Derby

Tags: backup, derby

Apache database hosted in a virtual server to be used with a JSF and JPA application.It there any method where regular back ups can be performed, for example once a day? Like an script?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a lot of information about making backups of a Derby database: http://db.apache.org/derby/docs/10.9/adminguide/cadminhubbkup98797.html

Choose a backup method that works well for you, then use your operating system's scheduling tools (cron, etc.) to arrange for that backup to be performed regularly.